# AppleScript/JavaSript to highlight matched text in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I have the following script which will take some value from the clipboard, return them individually, and highlight matching text in the current safari window :

```
set myNewList to {}

set myClipboard to the clipboard
set theList to words of myClipboard
##set theLength to (get length of mylist)


set ColortheList to {"009933", "000000", "660066", "660099", "003399", "0033ff", "336666", "339966", "339999", "3399cc", "3399ff", "33cc66", "006633", "006666", "006699", "0066cc", "33ffff", "9933cc", "0066ff", "009966", "3366ff", "993300", "993333", "339900", "009999", "0099cc", "0099ff", "6600cc", "6600ff", "663300", "663333", "663366", "9900ff", "663399", "6633cc", "6633ff", "666699", "00cc00", "339933", "00cc33", "00cc66", "00cc99", "00cccc", "993366", "00ccff", "00ff00", "336699", "ff3333", "3366cc", "00ff33", "33ff00", "6666cc", "6666ff", "ff9999", "669966", "66ff99", "993399", "990066", "990099", "9900cc", "ff0099", "66ffcc", "33ff33", "00ff66", "ffcccc", "33cc99", "ff66cc", "33cccc", "33ccff", "00ff99", "00ffcc", "33ffcc", "00ffff", "330066", "330099", "3300cc", "ff9999", "3300ff", "33ff66", "990033", "33ff99", "333300", "333333", "3333ff", "336600", "660000", "660033", "66ffff", "990000", "9933ff", "996600", "996666", "996699", "9966cc", "9966ff"}


repeat with a from 1 to length of theList
    copy ({item a of theList, some item of ColortheList}) to the end of the |myNewList|
    
end repeat



tell application "Safari"
    ## activate
    set theWindow to front window
    tell theWindow
        tell current tab
            repeat with colourPair in myNewList
                do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'on'"
                do JavaScript "var sel = window.getSelection(); sel.collapse(document.body, 0); while (window.find('" & (item 1 of colourPair) & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '" & (item 2 of colourPair) & "');}"
                do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'off'"
            end repeat
        end tell
        
    end tell
end tell
```

This work fine but this is slow, especially when I have 10+ variables.
on top of that if I accidentally press a key on my keyboard it would change the content of the page loaded on safari, also if I change tap while running, it's will make a error.

is they a way to speed up the script and improve the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the *code* you posted, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is how I'd rewrite your *code* to speed it up just a bit:

```applescript
set myNewList to {}

set theList to words of (the clipboard)

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set tempList to theList as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

set theSortedUniqList to paragraphs of ¬
    (do shell script "sort -u <<< " & tempList's quoted form)   

set ColortheList to {"009933", "000000", "660066", "660099", "003399", "0033ff", "336666", "339966", "339999", "3399cc", "3399ff", "33cc66", "006633", "006666", "006699", "0066cc", "33ffff", "9933cc", "0066ff", "009966", "3366ff", "993300", "993333", "339900", "009999", "0099cc", "0099ff", "6600cc", "6600ff", "663300", "663333", "663366", "9900ff", "663399", "6633cc", "6633ff", "666699", "00cc00", "339933", "00cc33", "00cc66", "00cc99", "00cccc", "993366", "00ccff", "00ff00", "336699", "ff3333", "3366cc", "00ff33", "33ff00", "6666cc", "6666ff", "ff9999", "669966", "66ff99", "993399", "990066", "990099", "9900cc", "ff0099", "66ffcc", "33ff33", "00ff66", "ffcccc", "33cc99", "ff66cc", "33cccc", "33ccff", "00ff99", "00ffcc", "33ffcc", "00ffff", "330066", "330099", "3300cc", "ff9999", "3300ff", "33ff66", "990033", "33ff99", "333300", "333333", "3333ff", "336600", "660000", "660033", "66ffff", "990000", "9933ff", "996600", "996666", "996699", "9966cc", "9966ff"}

repeat with anItem in theSortedUniqList
    copy {anItem, some item of ColortheList} to the end of the myNewList
end repeat

tell application "Safari"
    tell current tab of front window
        do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'on'"
        repeat with colourPair in myNewList
            do JavaScript "var sel = window.getSelection(); sel.collapse(document.body, 0); while (window.find('" & (item 1 of colourPair) & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '" & (item 2 of colourPair) & "');}"
        end repeat
        do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'off'"
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Notes**:

I did do some timing tests and there was a bit of improvement by not having to call `do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'on'"` and `do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'off'"` for each *item* in the *list* in the second `repeat` *loop*.

Added *code* to make the *list* sorted and uniq to avoid processing any duplicates words that may be on the clipboard.

Also writing the first `repeat` *loop* as I have negates the need for calculating the length of the list as it's irrelevant, and shaves a very small fraction of a second off.

This item didn't speed thing up but I also removed unnecessary characters, e.g., *parentheses* and *vertical pipe*.

I also use `set theList to words of (the clipboard)` instead of the two lines of *code* you used to get to the same results, `set myClipboard to the clipboard` and
`set theList to words of myClipboard` just to lessen the amount of *code* to write and IMO it's just easier to read, as it lessens the amount of *code* to read and maintain too.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's definitely faster and much clearer to read.

Comment: @Kevin, I've update the _code_ to make the _list_ sorted and uniq to avoid processing any duplicates _words_ that may be on _the clipboard_, thus making it faster when negating duplicate _words_.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by @user3439894 is definitely more efficient than the OP's code in his question, his solution can be optimized significantly more.

The optimization in my solution I learned from this resource…

[Learn AppleScript - The Comprehensive Guide to Scripting and Automation on Mac OS X, Third Edition](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430223610)

This following excerpt, taken directly from the resource I mentioned above, is what I copied to my clipboard, which will be processed in my optimization code.

> In theory, no matter how long the list is, the lookup time should be
> the same every time, but when we look at the results, we see that the
> time it takes to get the list item grows twice as large each time we
> double the size of the list—a linear increase, in other words, or O(n)
> efficiency. So if, for example, we were writing a script to loop over
> a variable number of items in a list, we would see the time it takes
> increase quadratically compared to the number of items in the list, or
> O(n*n). Ouch! That could really start to bite if you have, say,
> several thousand items to get through, perhaps even becoming the major
> performance bottleneck in your code. Fortunately, there is a
> “solution” of sorts that tricks AppleScript lists into performing
> constant-time lookups. If you wrap up your list in a script object
> property and refer to it there, something in the way that AppleScript
> references work causes whatever piece of the interpreter that is
> causing the slowdown to be bypassed.

```
set startTime to current date

set theList to words of (the clipboard)
log ((count of theList) as text) & " Words From Clipboard Processed"

set ColortheList to {"009933", "000000", "660066", "660099", "003399", "0033ff", "336666", "339966", "339999", "3399cc", "3399ff", "33cc66", "006633", "006666", "006699", "0066cc", "33ffff", "9933cc", "0066ff", "009966", "3366ff", "993300", "993333", "339900", "009999", "0099cc", "0099ff", "6600cc", "6600ff", "663300", "663333", "663366", "9900ff", "663399", "6633cc", "6633ff", "666699", "00cc00", "339933", "00cc33", "00cc66", "00cc99", "00cccc", "993366", "00ccff", "00ff00", "336699", "ff3333", "3366cc", "00ff33", "33ff00", "6666cc", "6666ff", "ff9999", "669966", "66ff99", "993399", "990066", "990099", "9900cc", "ff0099", "66ffcc", "33ff33", "00ff66", "ffcccc", "33cc99", "ff66cc", "33cccc", "33ccff", "00ff99", "00ffcc", "33ffcc", "00ffff", "330066", "330099", "3300cc", "ff9999", "3300ff", "33ff66", "990033", "33ff99", "333300", "333333", "3333ff", "336600", "660000", "660033", "66ffff", "990000", "9933ff", "996600", "996666", "996699", "9966cc", "9966ff"}

colorWords(theList, ColortheList)

on colorWords(someList, ColortheList)
    script fasterList
        property aList : someList
        property coloredList : ColortheList
        property myNewList : {}
    end script
    repeat with anItem in fasterList's aList
        copy {anItem, some item of fasterList's coloredList} to the end of fasterList's myNewList
    end repeat
    
    tell application "Safari"
        tell current tab of front window
            do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'on'"
            repeat with colourPair in fasterList's myNewList
                do JavaScript "var sel = window.getSelection(); sel.collapse(document.body, 0); while (window.find('" & (item 1 of colourPair) & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '" & (item 2 of colourPair) & "');}"
            end repeat
            do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'off'"
        end tell
    end tell
end colorWords

set timeTaken to ((current date) - startTime as string) & " Seconds"
```

This following image shows the results from processing 183 words from the clipboard. The left image is the results from my optimization technique, and the image on the right shows the results from the “Accepted Answer”

[image]

Processing the 183 words from the clipboard shows a 13 second time difference between the two. It's not a huge difference but look what happens when the clipboard contains 414 words.  OUCH!

In general, the bigger the list to be processed, the less efficient the code in the image on the right becomes.

[As to not clog up this post with unnecessary text, the 414 words added to my clipboard for the next test was taken from here.](https://pastebin.com/62KHv06d)
 (Which is a continuation of the excerpt taken directly from the resource I mentioned above.)

[image]

**Being that I used user3439894’s code to build upon, I think he should get the credit for the “Accepted Answer”**

Either way, the method which I have posted is significantly quicker.

You may also want to consider adding additional code to remove any duplicate words from your clipboard before passing those items on to the rest of the script to be processed